# рандом без повтора чисел?

Tags: python

при нажатии 1 раз на кнопку, нужно видать 1 число из 100 в рандомном порядке без повторения на протяжение 100 последовательных нажатий

как такое реализовать?

есть код, но он не работает

**Ошибка:** ***IndexError: list index out of range***

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):

l = list(range(1, 101)) 
rand = random.shuffle(l) 
row = db_worker.select_single(rand)
```

Comment: Что вы уже попробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: Очевидно же, что во второй раз надо выбирать из 99 оставшихся чисел, в третий - из 98 и так далее. Стоп, погодите, Вам, наверное, прямо готовый код нужен?

Comment: `Ошибка: IndexError: list index out of range` не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Не изменяйте вопрос таким образом, что перестаёт быть совместимым с уже существующими ответами. Это не форум, если есть новый вопрос—задайте его как новый вопрос (специально про `IndexError`): приведите полный traceback и создайте [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

1. Сгенерить последовательность от 1 до 100 с помощью range
2. Перемешать её с помощью random.shuffle
3. Итерироваться по этой последовательности по одному элементу на каждое нажатие кнопки.

Comment: есть такой код, но он не работает 

` l = list(range(1, 101))
     rand = random.shuffle(l)

     row = db_worker.select_single(rand) `

Comment: @Surfer `shuffle` ничего не возвращает, не нужно писать `rand = `.После перемешивания вытащите у списка элемент используя метод pop: `rand = l.pop()`

Comment: пробовал , так не работает

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(range(100))
shuffle(l)
l.pop()
```